# Speed optimization of Mean calculation in a previous calculated data range

Tags: performance-tuning

I have following problem:
My calculations work quite well with the shown testdata, the only problem is the speed of it. My original dataset is about 64000 datapoints, and it takes several minutes to calculate the following script. I have the clue that my 2 `For` loops could be the reason, has anyone an idea how I could speed it up??

I have following datasets

```
Signal={{1., 0.5}, {1.1, 0.721739}, {1.2, 0.860952}, {1.3, 0.932368}, {1.4, 
  0.966584}, {1.5, 0.982954}, {1.6, 0.990987}, {1.7, 0.995064}, {1.8, 
  0.997207}, {1.9, 0.998372}, {2., 0.999024}, {2.1, 0.999401}, {2.2, 
  0.999624}, {2.3, 0.999759}, {2.4, 0.999842}, {2.5, 0.999895}, {2.6, 
  0.999929}, {2.7, 0.999951}, {2.8, 0.999966}, {2.9, 0.999976}, {3., 
  0.999983}, {3.1, 0.999988}, {3.2, 0.999991}, {3.3, 0.999993}, {3.4, 
  0.999995}, {3.5, 0.999996}, {3.6, 0.999997}, {3.7, 0.999998}, {3.8, 
  0.999998}, {3.9, 0.999999}, {4., 0.999999}, {4.1, 0.999999}, {4.2, 
  0.999999}, {4.3, 1.}, {4.4, 1.}, {4.5, 1.}, {4.6, 1.}, {4.7, 
  1.}, {4.8, 1.}, {4.9, 1.}, {5., 1.}, {5.1, 1.}, {5.2, 1.}, {5.3, 
  1.}, {5.4, 1.}, {5.5, 1.}, {5.6, 1.}, {5.7, 1.}, {5.8, 1.}, {5.9, 
  1.}, {6., 1.}, {6.1, 1.}, {6.2, 1.}, {6.3, 1.}, {6.4, 1.}, {6.5, 
  1.}, {6.6, 1.}, {6.7, 1.}, {6.8, 1.}, {6.9, 1.}, {7., 1.}, {7.1, 
  1.}, {7.2, 1.}, {7.3, 1.}, {7.4, 1.}, {7.5, 1.}, {7.6, 1.}, {7.7, 
  1.}, {7.8, 1.}, {7.9, 1.}, {8., 1.}, {8.1, 1.}, {8.2, 1.}, {8.3, 
  1.}, {8.4, 1.}, {8.5, 1.}, {8.6, 1.}, {8.7, 1.}, {8.8, 1.}, {8.9, 
  1.}, {9., 1.}, {9.1, 1.}, {9.2, 1.}, {9.3, 1.}, {9.4, 1.}, {9.5, 
  1.}, {9.6, 1.}, {9.7, 1.}, {9.8, 1.}, {9.9, 1.}, {10., 1.}, {10.1, 
  1.}, {10.2, 1.}, {10.3, 1.}, {10.4, 1.}, {10.5, 1.}, {10.6, 
  1.}, {10.7, 1.}, {10.8, 1.}, {10.9, 1.}, {11., 1.}, {11.1, 
  1.}, {11.2, 1.}, {11.3, 1.}, {11.4, 1.}, {11.5, 1.}, {11.6, 
  1.}, {11.7, 1.}, {11.8, 1.}, {11.9, 1.}, {12., 1.}, {12.1, 
  1.}, {12.2, 1.}, {12.3, 1.}, {12.4, 1.}, {12.5, 1.}, {12.6, 
  1.}, {12.7, 1.}, {12.8, 1.}, {12.9, 1.}, {13., 1.}, {13.1, 
  1.}, {13.2, 1.}, {13.3, 1.}, {13.4, 1.}, {13.5, 1.}, {13.6, 
  1.}, {13.7, 1.}, {13.8, 1.}, {13.9, 1.}, {14., 1.}, {14.1, 
  1.}, {14.2, 1.}, {14.3, 1.}, {14.4, 1.}, {14.5, 1.}, {14.6, 
  1.}, {14.7, 1.}, {14.8, 1.}, {14.9, 1.}, {15., 1.}, {15.1, 
  1.}, {15.2, 1.}, {15.3, 1.}, {15.4, 1.}, {15.5, 1.}, {15.6, 
  1.}, {15.7, 1.}, {15.8, 1.}, {15.9, 1.}, {16., 1.}, {16.1, 
  1.}, {16.2, 1.}, {16.3, 1.}, {16.4, 1.}, {16.5, 1.}, {16.6, 
  1.}, {16.7, 1.}, {16.8, 1.}, {16.9, 1.}, {17., 1.}, {17.1, 
  1.}, {17.2, 1.}, {17.3, 1.}, {17.4, 1.}, {17.5, 1.}, {17.6, 
  1.}, {17.7, 1.}, {17.8, 1.}, {17.9, 1.}, {18., 1.}, {18.1, 
  1.}, {18.2, 1.}, {18.3, 1.}, {18.4, 1.}, {18.5, 1.}, {18.6, 
  1.}, {18.7, 1.}, {18.8, 1.}, {18.9, 1.}, {19., 1.}, {19.1, 
  1.}, {19.2, 1.}, {19.3, 1.}, {19.4, 1.}, {19.5, 1.}, {19.6, 
  1.}, {19.7, 1.}, {19.8, 1.}, {19.9, 1.}, {20., 1.}}
```

[image: Signal]

```
MicrowavePulse={{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}, {7, 0}, {8, 0}, {9,0}, {10, 0}, {11, 1}, {12, 1}, {13, 1}, {14, 1}, {15, 1}, {16, 0},{17, 0}, {18, 0}, {19, 0}, {20, 0}}
```

[image: MicrowavePulse]

My goal is to get the  `Mean`of Signal data, in the range whenever the MicrowavePulse is on and off. That means I want to get 4x (in this case) the `Mean`of all Signal data points lying from x=1 to x=5, from x=6 to x=10, from x=11 to x=15 and from x=16 till x=20.

I have written a `For` loop in order to receive sublists, for each time the MW is on or off, that means I get 4 sublists.

```
NumberMWData = Length[MicrowavePulse]
MicrowavePulse = MicrowavePulse[[All, 2]];
MWListOnOFF := {}; 
MWOneList := {};
For[i = 1, i <= NumberMWData, i++, 
MWOneList = Append[MWOneList, i]; 
If[i == NumberMWData || (MicrowavePulse[[i]] > 0 && 
 MicrowavePulse[[i + 1]] <= 0) || (MicrowavePulse[[i]] <= 0 && 
 MicrowavePulse[[i + 1]] > 0),
MWListOnOFF = Append[MWListOnOFF, MWOneList];
MWOneList = {}
]
]

(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18,19, 20}} *)
```

These lists are applied to cut the Signal data in the same x range like the MW pulse in lists, so that I can calculate the Mean in each of the Signal lists and the result are four mean values for the Signal data.

```
ResultMean := {}; 
For[i = 1, i <= Length[MWListOnOFF], i++,
start = MWListOnOFF[[i]][[1]];
stop = MWListOnOFF[[i]][[Length[MWListOnOFF[[i]]]]];
ResultMean = Append[ResultMean,Mean[Select[Signal, start <= #[[1]] <= stop &]]];
]

(*{{3., 0.974232}, {8., 1.}, {13., 1.}, {18., 1.}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
indices = SplitBy[MicrowavePulse, Last][[All, All, 1]]
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}} *)

Mean[Signal[[#]]] & /@ indices
(* {{1.2,0.796329},{1.7,0.992917},{2.2,0.99953},{2.7,0.999943}} *)
```

or

```
Extract[Signal, List /@ indices, Mean]
(* {{1.2,0.796329},{1.7,0.992917},{2.2,0.99953},{2.7,0.999943}} *)
```

Comment: Wow, that is great! The first code `SplitBy`...is super. But the second and third are not giving the right result, do you have a clue why?

Comment: @Jacccy, that's because `Signal` and `MicrowavePulse` have different lengths (191 and 20, respectively), and the functions posted are using the first 20 elements of `Signal`.

Comment: I have one additional question, if I want to split y-values in a specific range e.g (#2 > 0 && #1 <= 0) || (#1 > 0 && #2 <= 0)] & where do I have to add this in the code? And is my code correct?

Comment: Jacccy, if you want to split `yourlist` using the splitting rule in your comment, you can do `Split[yourlist,(#2 > 0 && #1 <= 0) || (#1 > 0 && #2 <= 0)&] ` or `Split[yourlist, Times@## <= 0 &]`.

Comment: I tried it with my original data and it seems that this code is not working with decimal x-values (1.1,2.3,...). With integers (1,2,...) it's no problem. The error "The expression {1.1,2.3,...} cannot be used as a part specification." occurs. Do you maybe also know how I can handle this problem?

Comment: @Jacccy, you do need integers as part indices. Not sure how you would like to use `1.1`, `2.3` etc as part indices --maybe you can use `Round` or `IntegerPart` to turn real values to integers.

Comment: it works just fine with  `IntegerPart`, thank you very much again!

Comment: Jacccy, my pleasure. Btw welcome to mma.se, and, in case you haven't, please read the [FAQs](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour).